# Replacing original index to the new index in dictionary and dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, indexing

I have a dataframe (origin_dataframe) with 12000 rows and 34 features (columns), and a dictionary (m_dict) with 12 keys as (‘m1’,’m2’, ...,’m12’) where in each key there is a dataframe including 1000 rows, as follows:

```
     origin_dataframe:

        index,  f1, f2, …,  f34
         0,     2,  45, …,  3
         4,     12, 5,  …,  6
                   …
         1230,  4,  3,  …,  8
                   ….
         4500,  9, 34,  …,  89
         5001,  10, 54, …,  23
                   ….
         76000,  3, 8,  …,   9



     m_dict.keys():

               dict_keys(['m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7',  
                     'month8', 'm9', 'm10', 'm11', 'm12'])

     m_dict[‘m1’]:
                 index, f1, f2, …,   f34
                    0,  2,  45, …,    3
                    1,  4,  3,  …,    8
                    3, 10,  54, …,    23
                    …. 
                  1000, 23, 43, ...,  77

      m_dict[‘m2’]:
                 index, f1, f2, …,   f34
                     0,     12, 5,  …,    6
                     1,     10, 54, …,   23
                               ….
                  1000,    34, 1,  ...,  67
```

Indeed the content of the ‘origin_dataframe’ is grouped and divided into different sub-dataframes in the dictionary, but with different index e.g., from 0 to 1000. My question is how I can change their current index (0-1000) to their original index which is available in the original_dataframe? My desired output e.g., for the first sub_dataframe in the dictionary should be like this:

```
        m_dict[‘m1’]:
                 index,    f1,  f2, …,   f34
                     0,     2,  45, …,    3
                  1230,     4,   3, …,    8
                  5001,    10,  54,    …, 23
```

…

Comment: Can you do it during the splitting process? Maybe provide additional info on how they get assigned a group? Because the way I see it otherwise you'll have to search each line by matching all 34 of the numbers and even then there's no guarantee there aren't any identical entries.

Comment: No, it is not possible during the split.

Comment: At the moment, I am using -for loops- to check line by line, it works, but it is really time consuming :(

Comment: The reason i'm asking is you can see from example data that first item got into 1st group, 2nd into 2nd, so if that is indeed how grouping is done (pretty much just equal split) then you can use that to find their original index. Otherwise you can making a hashmap of all entries of original dataset using values as key and index as value and searching such hashmap will be faster than matching one by one. Idk if  python can do it out of the box, but if not it shouldn't be too hard to make one.